# NioEndpoint never timing out in Spring Boot integration test

Tags: spring-boot, grails, tomcat9

I am trying to provoke a server timeout in an integration test, by placing a sleep loop in my Controller. I do appreciate people wanting to help out, but please don't ask why I am doing this, or suggest better ways of doing what you think I am trying to achieve: I just want to see the timeout happen, or understand why it is not happening.

To do that, I have set connection-timeout to a small value.

```
server:
  tomcat:
    connection-timeout: 1000
```

I can see that the socket timeout is set to that small value, in the `SocketWrapper`, so configuration-wise I think I'm OK.

However in NioEndpoint, I can see that the Poller is failing to evaluate true in this test:

```
} else if ((socketWrapper.interestOps() & SelectionKey.OP_READ) == SelectionKey.OP_READ ||
      (socketWrapper.interestOps() & SelectionKey.OP_WRITE) == SelectionKey.OP_WRITE) {
```

(This is library `tomcat-embed-core:9.0.4.1`, Line 951)

And it fails to evaluate to true, because `socketWrapper.interestOps()` is `0` every time except the first time my breakpoint is activated there, and the first time, the timeout should not occur yet.

Is there anything I can do differently?